# How to set a function pointer from another function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to do the following:

```
void *f1(int);
void *f2(int);

f1 = f2;
```

It says it cant convert `void*(int)` to `void*(int)`

I basically need this for a keyboard handler. Where all objects point to the main keyboard handler function pointer address and then set it to point to their own keyboard handler when one of them get selected by the mouse.

I want to do this for good code design principles and to know in general.

If there is any way to allow objects to set the keyboard handler please let me know. There could be some trick using strictures or dynamice polymorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `f1` and `f2` to be functions taking an `int` argument and returning `void*`. Functions are, of course, not assignable.

To declare `f1` and `f2` as pointers to functions taking an `int` argument and returning `void`, you need to use parentheses:

```
void (*f1)(int);
void (*f2)(int);
```

Comment: Will check it as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way to do it would be:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1;
std::function<void(int)> f2;
```

Comment: The cpp way will be not to pay overhead, unless needed